# SSRS Design Surface fields for each row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a report and for each row I have several fields defined in the design surface. However I cannot figure out a way to keep those fields together for each row.

This is the report design -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrwi8.jpg

The output is rendering as -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXqJz.jpg

I need all those fields defined in the report to appear for each row separately.

EDIT: The output needs to look something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyJOE.jpg

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the dataset output and what you intend the report to render.

Comment: Each ApplicationNumber is unique and has data in all those fields defined in the report design. The client wants the data to be displayed in the format but some of the fields are now in the design surface area. When the report is rendered, for each application we need to see the data in each of those fields. Currently it is displaying the design surface fields at the end of the report when it should be repeated for each row.

Comment: Please just update your question to show what your expected output to be. people here are willing to help but they cannot read minds or understand your business and its reporting needs.

Comment: The output needs to be like this -> https://i.imgur.com/ajaVepS.jpg

Comment: The left-most part of your design window is missing.

Comment: @WolfgangKais I don't understand?

Comment: You understood me very well, as I can see from the solution you have figured out all by yourself. That left-most part you have hidden from your screenshot would have contained a symbol indicating the group membership of your additional rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I created additional rows below by right clicking the data row and inserting rows in the group.

Thanks.